# Any way to create custom language packs for windows?

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

I'm a conlanger (someone who creates/makes languages for fun) and I'm looking to somehow create or modify a windows language pack with custom symbols (i.e. I want to be able to type in this language). Is there any way to do this? I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify: "conlang" is short for "constructed language", an artificial natural language.

Comment: No, there is no way to make your own language pack